# Converges of $\sum\frac{2^{{(-1)}^n}}{(\sqrt{n}+e)^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Exercise 7.14 part 3 from  https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/bfa73f6f-a5bb-4790-8177-7a63da52655e

Prove that $\sum\frac{2^{{(-1)}^n}}{(\sqrt{n}+e)^3}$ converges.

Comment: If you want an answer, please write your question in a proper way

Comment: Excuse me i don't know how use TEX !!

Comment: Take a moment [to learn $\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: In order to post here, you should learn

Comment: @SimpleArt THANK U !!

Comment: (its on the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Comparison test:
$$\frac{2^{(-1)^n}}{(\sqrt n+\mathrm e)^3}\le\frac{2}{n^{3/2}}.$$